# Textbox property changes back after recursive component list

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, recursion, components

I have a form with a TabControl with controls.

After instance the form, i call a function to prepare it to recive values.

That function changes the Text property from "0" to some value.
Some lines later, i call a inherited function that recursively list all TextBoxes on form and add to a Object List

When recursive function ends i look at the list, and my textbox have the previous value.

---

Aditional Info

```
 // Textbox.text has "0"

    textBox.Text = "123";

 //Other components change

PrepareForm(); //inherited function that enumerates all TextBoxes (and other components) on that form in a list
```

Inside PrepareForm():

```
// Value is "123"
List<Control> lstControls = new List<Control>();

foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    ListControls(lstControls, c);
} 

// The textbox on the list has the old value ("0") <- Edited
```

---

```
protected void ListControls(List<Control> Controls, Control control)
    {
        if (control.HasChildren)
        {
            foreach (Control c in control.Controls)
            {
                ListControls(Controls, c);
            }
        }
 }
```

EDIT:
The form calls InitializeComponent() and fill the textbox with "0", then form_load returns. I Change the value to "123" and call PrepareForm(), just after call, the textbox value is "123", then i call the recusrive function, when this recursive function returns, the value is changed back to "0"

Comment: Textbox is changing back the value is a problem... the problem is the question...

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this happen when setting a value on a control that exists on a `TabPage` that has not yet been made visible. In other words, because the `TabPage` hasn't yet been made visible, the line...

```
textBox.Text = "123";
```

...doesn't fail, but it also doesn't do anything. The only way I could get around this was the store the value in some kind of cached variable and then consume the control's `OnVisibleChanged` and set the value there.

This is an unfortunate optimization made by the `TabControl`.

Comment: it´s make sense, all this occur before form.show
PS: all code is executed (i tested with breakpoints)

Comment: @Rafael, yeah, it's not something you're going to be able to change, you're just going to have to work around it.

Comment: i'll test it and return with result.
Thanks

Comment: The code is executed and just after the recursive calls the value has changed. Before the form has shown. I Checked the Text Property in the debugger.

Comment: @Rafael, bear in mind that it did work (depending on when I set the `Text` property), for controls on the first `TabPage`, but never worked for controls on subsequent hidden `TabPage`'s.

Comment: @Rafael, I don't understand what you mean, please elaborate.

Comment: The form calls InitializeComponent() and fill the textbox with "0", then form_load returns. I Change the value to "123" and call PrepareForm(), just after call, the textbox value is "123", then i call the recusrive function, when this recursive function returns, the value is changed back to "0"